# Writing Array Back to Spreadsheet at Multiple Different Places

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am attempting to simplify my code when writing back data from an array into an Excel spreadsheet.
I have an array of 2 rows and 49 columns (the data is dates used for the horizontal part in a number of graphs). The date's adapt based on user-input and it is then written back into the Excel spreadsheet.
Currently I have written below code for loading the data into the array and writing it back into the spreadsheet (and it works as intended).

```
Dim LocalArray() As Variant
LocalArray = Sheets("Data").Range("L4003:BH4004").Value2
.Range("M280").Resize(UBound(LocalArray, 1), UBound(LocalArray, 2)) = LocalArray
.Range("M336").Resize(UBound(LocalArray, 1), UBound(LocalArray, 2)) = LocalArray
.Range("M394").Resize(UBound(LocalArray, 1), UBound(LocalArray, 2)) = LocalArray
```

Above is only part of the code though as I need to include the array in 15 different places (graphs). Hence I repeat the same line of code a lot of times which seems very ineffecient.

I have tried using below simple line of code to write the array data back into the spreadsheet:

```
.Range("M280:BI281,M336:BI337,M394:BI395").Value2 = LocalArray
```

However, writing back the array data using above code makes every second range appear wrong with cells including N/A (ref. below picture).

[image]

How do I write this code the simplest way possible (and requiring as little processing power from the user's PC as possible)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to examine and remember the dimensions of the **source range**.

Say we have data in a rectangular set of cells from **B2** through **D3**:

[image]

That we wish to copy elsewhere several times.  The first time will be a block starting at **E6**:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim LocalArray() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Long, cl As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D4")
    rw = rng.Rows.Count
    cl = rng.Columns.Count

    LocalArray = rng.Value2

    Range("E6").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray
End Sub
```

Running this yields:

[image]

So all we need to remember is `rw` and `cl`.

**EDIT#1:**

For an easy way to loop the deposits:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim LocalArray() As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Long, cl As Long
    Dim a

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:D4")
    rw = rng.Rows.Count
    cl = rng.Columns.Count

    LocalArray = rng.Value2

    Range("E6").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray

    ' Now try looping

    For Each a In Array("a12", "b16", "c23")
        Range(a).Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray
    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried including the code and it worked very nicely!

One question though, can the writing to the individual cells be done in one line of code? Or must it be included seperately (like below)?

Range("M280").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray

Range("M336").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray

Range("M394").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray

Range("M452").Resize(rw, cl) = LocalArray

Excel won't allow me to include multiple cells in the Range specification (i.e. Range("M280,M336,M394,M452")....)

Comment: @Philip  See my **EDIT#1**